# Best practice for disabling and enabling all buttons

Tags: jquery

Is this the best practice for disabling and enabling all buttons?

```
$("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");
```

or

```
$(":button").on('click',function() {
   $(this).prop("disabled",true);
});
$(":button").on('click',function() {
   $(this).prop("disabled",false);
});
```

or something else?

Answer (score 3):

From the jQuery docs, http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc-1:

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without
>   changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value
>   property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and
>   buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method
>   should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr()
>   method.

So you should be using `.prop("disabled", true)` or `.prop("disabled", false)`

Comment: Updated the .prop() documentation link to skip to the nearest id of the blockquote.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=button]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");
```

looks good but you probably need some sort of event as well like a click or a submit or something equivalent I guess.

Comment: Please refer to my answer and the jQuery docs. That is not considered best practice.